# Access members/function from a generic object created via reflection without reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, generics, reflection

I have a a type available:

```
Type arg1 = GetGenericType(3); // based on the number passed a type is received.
```

I want to create an object of a generic type : `MyGenericType<T>`, so I do this:

```
Type g1 = typeof(MyGenericType<>);
Type g2 = g1.MakeGenericType(arg1);
```

Now I have a type stored in "g2" of type `MyGenericType<T>`, here "T" is of type arg1.
Next I create an instance of this type like:

```
object objG = Activator.CreateInstance(g2);
```

Now I have the object of generic type stored in "objG". Next I need to access some members from "objG". I could use reflection to do it. But is there an easy way to do it ? Like store this object in some object through which I can access its member or typecast "objG" into MyGenericType ?

Comment: Depends on your definition of 'easy'... easy as in easier to understand, easier to type, easier on the CPU of the PC?

Comment: easy to understand and type, so that I don't have to go the reflection way.

Comment: presumably the methods you're calling have a known signature that doesn't depend on the type parameter, otherwise you need to know the type to call them anyway (as you'd have arguments of the appropriate type in your code)... so given that can you declare an interface on MyGenericType<T> that doesn't depend on the type parameter and cast to that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it by taking advantage of [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264741.aspx), simple example below:

```
dynamic listInt = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof (List<int>));
listInt.Add(3);

int count = listInt.Count;
```

Comment: What if I am using VB.NET and Strict option is on ?

Comment: @Brij: why your tag is in C#?

Comment: I have to use both C# and VB, is there a way to do it in VB ? 
(I have edited the tag to include VB as well)

Comment: @Brij: Well I don't know VB.NET, you can ask another question

Comment: There is no equivalent in VB.NET with Strict On, as there is no dynamic keyword in VB.NET.  This is basically what Strict On means, as you can mark some code as Strict Off and dynamic would then be Object.

Comment: @JamesGaunt, how can we mark "some" code as Strict Off ? Does that "some" mean not the whole project, just some piece of code ?

Comment: I thought the Strict option could be applied at the file level, but I'm not a VB expert so could be wrong.  Try just writing 'Option Strict Off' at the top of the file.